# How to compare the resistance of various elements?

Tags: electricity

Resistance is a function of distance. How to compare the resistance of various materials independent of distance?

Comment: With resistivity. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrical_resistivity_and_conductivity

Comment: @RedAct If you write it up I will accept it as the answer.

Comment: why the down vote?

Comment: I didn't downvote, but the likely reason is that this is the kind of question that gets asked for homework or exams. Further because the reason you'd ask it on an exam is because the answer is very obvious if you've read and understood the basic explanation of resistance from any Physics 1 textbook.

Comment: For example, it can be answered just by reading the [Introduction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrical_resistance_and_conductance#Introduction) section of the Wikipedia article on electrical resistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Resistivity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrical_resistivity_and_conductivity) is the [intrinsic property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intrinsic_and_extrinsic_properties) of a material that measures how much the material opposes the flow of current, but does not reflect the dimensions of the object made out of the material. With an object made out of the material which has a uniform cross section and electrical contacts on the two ends, the material's resistivity and the object's resistance between the contacts are related as

$$R=\frac{\rho\ \ell}{A}\ \ ,$$

where $\rho$ is the material's resistivity, $\ell$ is the length of the object, $A$ is the object's cross-sectional area, and $R$ is the resulting resistance.